# Mobile responsive website using Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, mobile, wordpress-theming, responsive

I have been trying to create a mobile responsive website from the 'Zerif' Wordpress theme.

Would anybody be able to explain how this would be possible? Below is my website.

https://www.vidinfluence.com/homepage/sign-up/

Many thanks,

David

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, Wordpress is not the best option to attempt to create a responsive site - at least out of an already made theme. You would have to write a large amount of custom CSS media queries to achieve this.

Your best bet would be to start fresh with a Wordpress theme that is already responsive.

Otherwise, I'd recommend starting fresh and building a Bootstrap responsive site from scratch. There are several free, or very inexpensive, Bootstrap theme packs that come with hundreds of elements to use.

Bootstrap themes and templates: https://startbootstrap.com/

Good luck!